Could not find the computed index field type
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find the computed index field type: Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search.Helpers.PdfComputedField, Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find the computed index field type: Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search.Helpers.PdfComputedField, Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Could not find the computed index field type: Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search.Helpers.PdfComputedField, Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentBuilderOptions.CreateComputedIndexField(String fieldName, XmlNode configNode) +518
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions.AddComputedIndexField(XmlNode configNode) +80

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +216
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +182
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +853
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +842
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +309
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +732
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +189
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.get_CsConfig() +16
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.GeAllIndexes() +11
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.DefaultSolrStartUp..ctor(BaseSearchIndexes indexes) +59
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process(PipelineArgs args) +72
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +490
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +215
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +1201
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719


The error indicates that Sitecore is trying to use a computed index field (PdfComputedField) defined in the class Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search.Helpers.PdfComputedField from the assembly Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search, but it cannot locate the type or assembly.
Here’s how you can troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

Verify Assembly Presence
Check the bin folder of your Sitecore instance to ensure the Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search.dll assembly is present.
If the assembly is missing:
Obtain it from your source control or build it from your solution.
Deploy it to the bin folder of your Sitecore instance.

Validate Assembly Configuration
Open the App_Config folder and locate the configuration file where the PdfComputedField is referenced.
Confirm that the fully qualified name of the computed field matches the class and namespace in the Suncor.Sitecore.PCL.Search assembly.


